# control number of threads used in cnc/tbb

Tags: pthreads, tbb, concurrent-collections

I am using intel cnc library and it creates as many threads as there are cores. Is there any way to control the number of threads used for the purpose and possibly control their placement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure about cnc, but since you tagged this question as `tbb`, there's a class [`tbb::task_scheduler_init`](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/files/documentation/a00169.html) which takes number of threads as ctor arg

Comment: Hi Andy, I asked the same at intel forum. It turns out for Cnc we use the CNC_NUM_THREADS environment variable and its not possible to control the placement of threads.